# MySql get one record from two identical tables with a check

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get same records from two identical tables but with a check.

I have following two tables that are identical :

`table_1`

```
id  | enc   | first_name | last_name | address | city
1   | 1001  | John       | Doe       | abc     |
```

`table_2`

```
id  | enc   | first_name | last_name | address | city
1   | 1001  |            | Doe       |         | xyz
```

I want to get record from table_2 but since `first_name` and `address` are empty it should the from record `table_1`
But again `city` is empty in `table_1` so it would get the record from `table_2`

I've tried the union like this :

```
(SELECT * from `table_1` where `id` = `1) 
UNION 
(SELECT * from `table_2` where `id` = `1)
```

But its providing both the records from the table. I want only one record using both the table like this :

```
id  | enc   | first_name | last_name | address | city
1   | 1001  | John       | Doe       | abc     | xyz
```

Comment: Have to ask why you have two tables?  This leads to exactly the problems your having of different data in different tables.  What if the values are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(T1.id,T2.ID) ID,IFNULL(T1.enc,T2.ENC)ENC,IFNULL(T1.first_name,T2.first_name)first_name , IFNULL(T1.last_name ,T2.last_name )last_name ,
IFNULL(T1.address ,T2.address )address ,
IFNULL(T1.city,T2.city)address 
 from `table_1` T1
INNER JOIN `table_2` T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID
```

Try above query.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.enc, table1.first_name, table2.last_name, table1.address, table2.city
INNER JOIN table2 on table2.id = table1.id
```

Supposing you always want to get specific fields from one of the tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT table_2.id,table_2.enc,table_1.first_name,table_2.last_name,table_1.address,table_2.city 
FROM table_2,table_1
WHERE table_2.id=table_1.id 
AND table_2.id=1;
```